# WSL 2 cannot conect to MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am developing a web app in my local using WSL 1 a while back. It works perfectly with MongoDB on local but after upgrading to WSL 2, I could not connect at all. I can still run the react app.

Here are some details:
Version: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.172]
WSL 2: Ubuntu

How am I gonna call the MongoDB from the windows side from the WSL 2?

Comment: You need to provide more details besides the operating system. Are you sure that MongoDB is still installed? Can you get into the `mongo` repl?

Comment: Yes I'm sure it is installed. As I've said, the web app works perfectly prior to upgrading to WSL 2.

Comment: I was referring to the upgrade, and the fact that you can't connect to it. So, you are sure it is installed, but you can't access it, is this correct? Not even from the repl? I'm not talking about your web app now, I'm saying can you run the mongo shell from the command line in WSL 2. When you type in `mongo` in the terminal, do you get the connection info and then a prompt like `test`? Are you sure that `mongod` is running in WSL 2? You may need to start the process by running `sudo mongod`.

Comment: I am not running the mongo on WSL. I have Robo 3T installed so I'm pretty sure it is installed. I can run mongo and mongod

Comment: OK, can you post the relevant connection code from your react app, and whatever errors you are getting from wherever you are connecting to MongoDB? I use Ubuntu, and just start up `mongod` in a terminal window and then connect through my apps, or through the `mongo` repl, but I think the logic is going to be similar, I just need to see what you have that is connecting first.

Comment: Bro, I gave up. I downgraded my OS from insider to regular build and everything works perfectly.

Comment: Solution mentioned here worked for me https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5486. Basically start Mongo with IP bind 0.0.0.0 and then connect using `mongodb://user:pass@IP_HOST:27017/dbname` where you can find host IP from `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

Mongodb listening on 127.0.0.1 by default.
You may want to edit your /etc/mongodb.conf to make mongodb listen on 0.0.0.0 so we can access mongodb from windows.

Or you can use this https://github.com/shayne/go-wsl2-host service to resolve your wsl 2 ip address to host name like ubuntu.wsl, then use that hostname instead of localhost

Answer (score 1):

Solution mentioned here worked for me github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5486.

Basically start Mongo with IP bind 0.0.0.0. If running as a service then update the file `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\X.X\bin\mongod.cfg` and then connect using `mongodb://user:pass@IP_HOST:27017/dbname` where you can find host IP by running the command `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mongod.exe --bind_ip=0.0.0.0
```

OR with WSL IP

```
mongod.exe --bind_ip=192.***.**.1
```

[Source](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5486#issuecomment-650271057)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting authentication errors.

Go to task manager and stop all mongodb process & restart. I didn't have to change any ip or port.